# Directional derivative of a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I've been asked to compute the directional derivative of $f(x) = 0.5\cdot |Ax|^2$ where $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. By definition
\begin{align}
\partial_v f(x) &= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{|A(x+tv)|^2 - |Ax|^2}{2t}\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{|Ax+t\cdot Av|^2 - |Ax|^2}{2t}.
\end{align}
but I can't seem to go anywhere from here without using inequalities.

Comment: Presumably the place to start is expanding the squared norm, e.g., $\|Ax\|^2=Ax\cdot Ax$. This should allow you to cancel some of the $t$ terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is differentiable, then you're in luck, because then the directional derivative is just $\partial_v f(x)=\mathrm Df_x(v)$, where $\mathrm Df_x$ is the differential of $f$ at $x$.

Proving differentiability for things involving matrices is usually quite thankful, since their linearity makes a suitable decomposition easy. In general, a function $f$ is differentiable at $x$ iff there is a linear map $A$ (possibly depending on $x$) such that

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+A(h)+r(h),$$

where $r$ is some small remainder which goes to $0$ faster than linearly. More specifically: $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{r(h)}{\vert h\vert}=0$. And then $A$ is the differential $\mathrm Df_x$.

In this specific case we have

$$\begin{align}
f(x+h)&=\frac12\vert A(x+h)\vert^2\\
&=\frac12[A(x+h)]^tA(x+h)\\
&=\frac12(x+h)^tA^tA(x+h)\\
&=\frac12( x^tA^tAx+x^tA^tAh+h^tA^tAx+h^tA^tAh)\\
&=\frac12(x^tA^tAx+2x^tA^tAh+h^tA^tAh)\\
&=\frac12x^tA^tAx+x^tA^tAh+\frac12h^tA^tAh.
\end{align}$$

Here I used the linearity of matrix multiplication and the fact that $h^tA^tAx$ is a scalar, so transposing it does nothing, so it's equal to $x^tA^tAh$. Anyway, in the end we get three summands: the first is just $f(x)$. The second is linear in $h$, and the third is the remainder. I leave it to you to show that it actually satisfies the conditions placed on the remainder. But in the end we find that $f$ is differentiable with differential $\mathrm Df_x(h)=x^tA^tAh$. So your directional derivative is

$$\partial_v f(x)=\mathrm Df_x(v)=x^tA^tAv.$$

Comment: Thank you I forgot the identity $|Ax|^2 = (Ax)^T(Ax)$.